# Dropwizard/Jersey: Missing dependency for method at parameter at index X

Tags: maven, jersey, dropwizard

I'm getting these missing dependency errors using Dropwizard:

```
ERROR [2013-07-31 22:17:01,918] com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public com.pronto.mpds.domain.MerchantProfileGroup com.pronto.mpds.service.MPDSResource.getMerchantProfiles(java.util.List,java.util.List) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public com.pronto.mpds.domain.MerchantProfileGroup com.pronto.mpds.service.MPDSResource.getMerchantProfiles(java.util.List,java.util.List) at parameter at index 1
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public com.pronto.mpds.domain.MerchantCpcData com.pronto.mpds.service.MPDSResource.getMerchantCpcData(java.lang.String,com.google.common.base.Optional) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public com.pronto.mpds.domain.MerchantCpcData com.pronto.mpds.service.MPDSResource.getMerchantCpcData(java.lang.String,com.google.common.base.Optional) at parameter at index 1
```

My Resource class looks like this:

```js
@Path("merchants")
public class MPDSResource {

    @GET
    @Path("{merchantId}/profile")
    @Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
    public MerchantProfile getMerchantProfile(@PathElem("merchantId") String merchantId) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not yet implemented");
    }

    @GET
    @Path("featured")
    @Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
    public FeaturedMerchantGroup getFeaturedMerchants(@RequestParam(value = "browseId") String browseId) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not yet implemented");
    }

    @GET
    @Path("profile")
    @Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
    public MerchantProfileGroup getMerchantProfiles(
            @RequestParam(value = "merchantIds", delimiter = "|") List<String> merchantIds,
            @RequestParam(value = "selectors", delimiter = "|") List<String> selectors) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not yet implemented");
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{merchantId}/cpc")
    @Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
    public MerchantCpcData getMerchantCpcData(@PathElem("merchantId") String merchantId,
            @RequestParam(value = "mexpCategoryIds", delimiter = "|") Optional<List<String>> mexpCategoryIds) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

There are four methods, but the errors are only happening for the methods that take multiple parameters.

Here are my jersey dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.14</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.14</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.14</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.14</version>

    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.14</version>
</dependency>
```

I've confirmed that I am using consistent Jersey versions in my Maven imports. I've confirmed that the web module, which contains the above Resource class, contains a Maven dependency on the package containing the custom PathElem and RequestParam classes. I can't think of any other possibilities. Anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: Note: I get these errors at runtime.

Comment: Note: I changed the List<String> type params to plain String type to see if that would fix the error and it did not. When I removed one of the params in the offending method signatures, it stopped causing the error. It seems pretty clear that it has to do with there being multiple parameters in the method signature.

Comment: I also posted the question to the dropwizard mailing list and Coda Hale replied: "You seem to be mixing Spring MVC annotations with Jersey. I've never tried it, but I'd be surprised if that works.
I'd suggest using the standard JAX-RS @PathParam and friends instead." I'm hoping s/he will answer the question here on SO, so I'm holding off on answering it myself. But maybe that will help you.

Comment: Thanks - investigating!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also posted the question to the dropwizard mailing list and Coda Hale replied: "You seem to be mixing Spring MVC annotations with Jersey. I've never tried it, but I'd be surprised if that works. I'd suggest using the standard JAX-RS @PathParam and friends instead." HTH somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

I was using @FormParam. But changing it to @RequestParam resolved the issue.